# In c typedef shouldn't the variable name be after the parentheses?

Tags: c++, typedef

in the following code I don't understand why BMP2() is inside the parentheses and why the fields inside it are written this way :

```
typedef struct BMP2
{
  unsigned long biSize;
  unsigned long biWidth;
  unsigned long biHeight;
  unsigned short biPlanes;
  unsigned short biBitCount;
  unsigned long biCompression;
  unsigned long biSizeImage;
  unsigned long biXPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned long biYPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned long biClrUsed;
  unsigned long biClrImportant;
  BMP2()
  {
    biWidth
    = biHeight
    = biCompression
    = biSizeImage
    = biXPelsPerMeter
    = biYPelsPerMeter
    = biClrUsed
    = biClrImportant = 0;
    biSize = sizeof(BMP2);
    biPlanes = biBitCount
    = 0;
  }
};
```

Comment: The `BMP2()` is a constructor. The `typedef` keyword is superfluous here and I don't think it should compile (missing a name at the end).

Comment: ...no, `BMP2()` is not inside parentheses... It's just a function inside a `struct`. In C++, it's a constructor.

Comment: @ForceBru um, call me old-fashioned, but in my C, there's no functions inside structs.

Comment: Clearly not valid C code - tag removed.  The typedef is superfluous in C++, `BMP2` _is_ a type name.

Comment: It being C++: maybe you want to tell the original author of that code about 1. initializer lists and 2. about initialized class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration looks like a `typedef` declaration without a declarator. (And it is not clear what "variable names after the parentheses" you are talking about.)

C++17 explicitly prohibits `typedef` declarations without a declarator, meaning that your code is ill-formed

> **7.1.3 The typedef specifier**
>   **1** [...] If a `typedef` specifier appears in a declaration without a declarator, the program is ill-formed.

Previous versions of C++ standard did not include that wording (at least in such straightforward form).

Since class (and enum) declarations in C++ can omit declarators (and, possibly, since in C `typedef` was simply a storage-class specifier) it is not clear to me whether it was supposed to be formally legal in pre-C++17 language. Many C++ compilers allow it, ignoring the redundant `typedef`. In that case what you have is a plain class declaration for class `BMP2`.

Answer (score 0):

`BMP2()` is the constructor of the structure.

This

```
biWidth
= biHeight
= biCompression
= biSizeImage
= biXPelsPerMeter
= biYPelsPerMeter
= biClrUsed
= biClrImportant = 0;
```

is an alternative way to do this:

```
biWidth = 0;
biHeight = 0;
biCompression = 0;
biSizeImage = 0;
biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
biClrUsed = 0;
biClrImportant = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`BMP()` - constructor for struct `BMP`. In c++ allowed initialized variables as in your code. Example:

```
int var1, var2, var3;
var1 = var2 = var3 = 4;
std::cout << "var1: " << var1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "var2: " << var2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "var3: " << var3 << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
var1: 4
var2: 4
var3: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Initialisations can be chained till the semicolon for example

```
a = b = c = d = e = f = 0;
```

Here everything will be initialised to `0`

This can also be written in multiline

```
a 
= b
= c
= d
= f
= 0;
```

This is what being done in your case

As far as `BMP2()` is concerned, its a special function of C++ called "CONSTRUCTOR" which will be called automatically every time the class is instantiated.